# Sort predefined list of items in node form

Tags: nodes

I got a tasks I am unsure how to solve the best way.

I need a list of items in my node add/edit forms, that should be able to be sorted, enabled/disabled on each node.

Eg.
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
Task 4.

NID 1 may have it sorted
Task 1, Task 4, Task 2, Task 3

NID may have it sorted
Task 3, Task 4 (and disabled Task 1 and Task 2)

And so on..

The best solution I came up with so far, is using the [Multiple Selects](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_selects) module. Creating a list of the tasks and lets users select and sort them this way. However it is not the best/most user friendly way.

Is there a module I have missed that can handle this a better way? Or is a custom module development needed.

The most beautiful way would be a UI like the "*Manage display*" in content type editing - since is it easy to see what is disabled and the order of the elements.

Comment: It have nothing to do with that post. It is creating a sortable field in the Views API. This is in the node edit/add form.

Comment: you could do it using field collection, but I think it would be prone to duplication (having 2 Task 1's).